# Django redirect URL to latest created blog post

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to have a redirect in my urls.py so that the latest Post entry in my Blog application is automatically loaded when people visit the Blog application index domain.

A Blog.Post detail is supplied via the blog.views.post_detail(request, slug) method and a blog post will end up with the URL:

```
www.example.com/blog/this-is-the-slug/
```

When someone loads the www.example.com/blog domain I want them to be automagically redirected to the latest blog post individual entry.

I'm very new to the urls.py and can't work out how to do this. I realise it would be fairly rudimentary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
url(r'^blog/$', 'blog.redirector'),
url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'blog.blog_post', name="blog_detail"),


def redirector(request):
     blog = Blog.objects.latest('id')
     return http.HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog_detail', args=[blog.slug]))
```

Alternative option, some people dislike reverse because it fails loudly.

You can define a `get_absolute_url` method on your blog post model that returns the absolute url, then your redirect is as simple as `http.HttpResponseRedirect(Blog.objects.latest('id').get_absolute_url()`)

Comment: I'm getting: `NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.` It looks like I'm heading in the right direction - any idea on this one?

Comment: Never mind, found it, had to move the args within the reverse method eg `return http.HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog_detail', args=[blog.slug]))`. Thanks, that works perfectly!

Comment: Oops, that was a typo! Sorry if that confused you for a while :D