# How can I made this random blog post redirect for my Django app more efficient

Tags: python, django, redirect, random, blogs

I have created a random blog post link on my site and the code it uses works. When I was creating it there was a problem making it work correctly since it kept saying 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'slug', so I came up with a work around. The work around makes more requests to the db than necessary (i think):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
def randompost(request):
    blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(post_status = 'published').order_by('?')[:1]
    blog_title = blog_posts[0]
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, title=blog_title)

    path = '/theblog/post/' + blog_post.slug + '/'

    return HttpResponseRedirect(path)
```

Ideally I would like a solution like [Django redirect URL to latest created blog post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440276/django-redirect-url-to-latest-created-blog-post)

Will it also need the correct http code since it's a redirect?

The old code with the Queryset error:

```
blog_post = BlogPost.objects.filter(post_status = 'published').order_by('?')[:1]
path = '/theblog/post/' + blog_post.slug + '/'

return HttpResponseRedirect(path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's better to use `redirect` and reverse URLs;
2. You could use `[]` syntax to get first object of QuerySet.

Updated code:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def randompost(request):
    blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(post_status='published').order_by('?')
    latest_post = blog_posts[0]

    return redirect('blog_post', latest_post.slug)
```

Updated:

URL sample, reverse is done by url name `blog_post`:

```
url(r'^post/(\w+)$', 'view_name', name='blog_post')
```

Comment: Is there anything I need to do in my models or urls as it now get a error of: Reverse for 'blog_post' with arguments '(u'flash-player-control-bar',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Ah excellent! Works :) Had to add the url bit on the front of mine, since mine was just a plain (r'post/....)

Answer (score 3):

As you may or may not be aware, the `.order_by('?')` is very inefficient, and is probably the biggest source of inefficiency in that code.

This is a more efficient (db wise) way to grab a random published post

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import Http404
from random import randint

def randompost(request):
    published_posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(post_status='published')
    count = published_posts.count()
    if count == 0:
        # Raise an error or something as there are no blog posts
        raise Http404
    random_index = randint(0, count - 1)
    random_post = published_posts[random_index] 

    # Then redirect to your post
    return redirect('blog_post', random_post.slug)
```

Comment: `random_post = random.choice(published_posts)`

Comment: I'm not sure how `random.choice()` works, but it could try to turn the `published_posts` queryset in to a list, which would be a big database lookup.