# Django redirecting URL view for the latest post

Tags: python, django, url

I am a novice to Django, so excuse me if this seems rather trivial.

I am trying to create a link to the latest issue for an online magazine. Here is my code:

home.html:

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load static%}
{% block content%}       
<button href="#"> Latest Issue</button>
{%endblock%}
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post, Issue
from .forms import PostForm, EditForm, IssueForm, IssueEditForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponse

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Issue
    template_name = "home.html"

class IssueView(ListView):
    model = Issue
    template_name='issues.html'

class IssueDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Issue
    template_name = 'issue_details.html'

    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IssueDetailView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()
        return context
#This is to pass in my post model, so I can display the posts for each issue in issue-details.html.
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .models import Post, Issue
#from . import views
from .views import HomeView, ArticleDetailView, AddPostView,EditPostView, DeletePostView,about_view, submit_view,IssueView, AddIssueView, IssueDetailView, EditIssueView

urlpatterns = [
    path('',HomeView.as_view(),name="home"),
   path('issue/',IssueView.as_view(), name="issue"), path('issue/<int:pk>', IssueDetailView.as_view(), name='issue-detail'),   
]
#Irrelevant urlpatterns omitted.
```

I looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440276/django-redirect-url-to-latest-created-blog-post), but I was not able to implement it, especially since it is from 9 years ago. I did not know what view to put/create for the redirecting url "latest-issue," which is where I think my problems are.  Here is my attempt:

```
\\home.html
<button href="{% url 'latest-issue'%}"> Latest Issue</button>

\\ urls.py
urlpatterns = [
   path('',HomeView.as_view(),name="home"),
   path('issue/',IssueView.as_view(), name="issue"), 
   path('issue/<int:pk>', IssueDetailView.as_view(), name='issue-detail'), 
   path('latest-issue/', latest-issue.redirector, name='latest-issue')
]
 
def redirector(request):
     issue = Issue.objects.latest('id')
     return http.HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('issue-detail', args=[issue.pk]))
```

What view should I put for the redirecting url so that it still calls the redirecting function?

Comment: Hi.
1) What is this object? latest-issue.redirector
2) What are you getting when you run the page?
3) It looks like you need a seperate url path and view function: 'get-latest-issue' which will check the most recent issue (only when button is clicked) and return a redirect

Comment: @Omri Shaffer I tried to replicate the solution I linked, but I don't think it works for my situation. I will try your approach instead, so disregard my failed attempt. Would I set up the code in the "redirector" function as a function based view "get_latest_issue" in views.py? Do I need to add anything more?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Omri Shaffer for helping me realize how to approach this differently. I created a url in my urls.py file that would pull up a function based view get_latest_issue:

```
from .views import get_latest_issue
path('latest-issue/', get_latest_issue, name='latest-issue')
```

I then defined the "redirector" function in views.py, making sure to import the correct functions:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def get_latest_issue(request): 
     issue = Issue.objects.latest('id')
     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('issue-detail', args=[issue.pk]))
```

I then changed my button in home.html to make it a link, which I did the wrong way in my first attempt:

```
<button onclick="location.href='{% url 'latest-issue' %}'"> Latest Issue</button>
```

I could also make the text a link and style it like a button with Bootstrap's btn class.

Comment: Happy to hear !

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question you need a link to all the latest issue in your model?
You overwriten the default queryset in you issueview
queryset=modelname.objects.order_by('-created-time')
In your model you should have a DateTimeField set to auto-now-add=true